# What does the following script lines does . ./pull.env and mailstatusFile=./.mailstatus

Tags: shell, unix

What does the following script lines does 
. ./pull.env  and   mailstatusFile=./.mailstatus

Please help

Answer (score 1):

the dot is a synonym for "source" -- it loads the script file in the current session.  So, say you had a script named foo with the contents:

```
 PS1="XXX"
```

If you execute that on the command line in bash, you see this:

```
 $
 $ PS1="XXX"
 XXX
```

as `XXX` becomes your prompt.

If you make that script executable and just run it, you see this:

```
 $ chmod a+x foo
 $ ./foo
 $
```

because what happens when you run a shell script is that the shell creates a new process.  The prompt changes in that new process, but not in the current one.

If you `source` the script, you get the same effect as if you'd typed it in the current shell

```
 $
 $ source ./foo
 XXX
```

...and as I said, '.' is a synonym for `source`

```
 $
 $ . ./foo
 XXX
```